# How do I automate exporting a DER encoded certificate for a site?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, openssl

I'd like to automate the following process with the openssl command:

- Open browser, go to https://www.google.com
- Inspect ssl cert
- Export it locally in DER format

I've been working along the lines of the following command (here wrapped in python):

local("echo -n | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -certform DER | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/google.com.der")

but it doesn't give me what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sed` command is only capturing `openssl s_client`'s standard output, but the certificate comes with the other debugging information on standard error. Have you tried something like this?

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 </dev/null 2>&1 |
  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' |
  openssl x509 -outform DER >/tmp/google.com.der
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing the lines which `openssl` outputs on stderr and are ignored by `sed`. You can just get rid of these before passing the output to `sed`:

```
% echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -certform DER 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF/DCCBWWgAwIBAgIKUCYyawAAAAB1rzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBGMQswCQYD
...
v6UdT7iXlxVh2oslpIksSw2bf0H7PUQQjFCMLVbiEMAQbXal4+SsyYB+GsPVvlR+
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```